# How to update the letsencrypt certificate after the IP is changed?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, nginx-config, certbot

I have an instance where I have configured nginx. I am using letsencrypt certificate. I configured everything when my server's IP was 123.123.123.123. The domain name I got was abc.dfg.hij. Now I restarted my EC2 instance so the public IP got changed. Now when I search on the old domain name it still points to old IP and it obviously fails.
I need to update this within my server. I tried to renew the certificate by running

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d abc.dfg.hij
```

But it is also trying to connect to the old IP (123.123.123.123). And that is failing by giving the following error

```
The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain ::  123.123.123.123
```

How do I update the IP address of the domain that I got.?
Does anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are issued to domain.
Your certificate should still be valid, just change the ip address mapped to that domain in your registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Update your dns server with new ip and domain